# dplyr replacing multiple strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with one column that contains names that need to be standardized.

here is an example:

```
PatientId<- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Visit_Date<- c("28/02/2014", "29/04/2014", "10/02/2014", "25/01/2014", "01/02/2014", "08/01/2014")
ClinicName<- c("A","A","A", "B","B","B")
PractitionerName<- c("Ahmad Mobin", "Amhad Mobin", "Ahmaad Mobin", "Hadley wickham", "Hadley Wuckham", "Hadley Wihcam")

example_df<- cbind(PatientId, Visit_Date, ClinicName, PractitionerName)
example_df<- as.data.frame(example_df)
```

This is the code on how I have been standardizing names, but was wondering if there is a much cleaner code that I can use:

```
example_df1<- example_df %>% 
              filter(str_detect(PractitionerName, "Mobin")==TRUE) %>% 
filter(ClinicName=="A") %>% 
mutate(PractitionerName="Ahmad Mobin")  

#Now adding those changes back to my main dataset `example_df`

temp_df<- example_df%>% anti_join(example_df1, by=c("PatientId", 
"Visit_Date"))   
example_df<-rbind(example_df1,temp_df)

#-Repeat the above process to standardize "Hadley Wickham"

  example_df1<- example_df %>% 
              filter(str_detect(PractitionerName, "Hadley")==TRUE) %>% 
 filter(ClinicName=="B") %>% 
 mutate(PractitionerName="Hadley Wickham")  

#Now adding those changes back to my main dataset `example_df`

temp_df<- example_df%>% anti_join(example_df1, by=c("PatientId", 
"Visit_Date"))   
 example_df<-rbind(example_df1,temp_df)
```

Comment: I usually just make a look up table and do a left join.

Comment: would you be able to provide a code?

Comment: Another option is `car::recode`

Comment: or `gsub` with different capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O...  I realized I did not read your question correctly.  I would do this task as follows, if you have lots of these you may want to wrap this in a function:

```
example_df$PractitionerName[grepl(".*Mobin.*", example_df$PractitionerName) & example_df$ClinicName == "A"] <- "Ahmad Mobin"
```

Comment: Hi Ian,

A potential issue with your code is if there are many common last names (or first names), which is why I first filtered by `ClinicName`. Sorry I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the problem, you could also consider using string distances

```
library(stringdist)
practitioners <- c("Ahmad Mobin", "Hadley Wickham")
example_df %>% 
  mutate(PractitionerName = 
           practitioners[apply(stringdistmatrix(PractitionerName, practitioners), 1, which.max)])

  PatientId Visit_Date ClinicName PractitionerName
1         1 28/02/2014          A   Hadley Wickham
2         1 29/04/2014          A   Hadley Wickham
3         1 10/02/2014          A   Hadley Wickham
4         2 25/01/2014          B      Ahmad Mobin
5         2 01/02/2014          B      Ahmad Mobin
6         2 08/01/2014          B      Ahmad Mobin
```

Comment: Clever use of `stringdistmatrix()`.

Comment: hmm interesting, but this might not work if Ahmad Mobin is spelt like Amahad Mobin. Because it was an open string field for Health care Practitioners to enter there might be a lot of variation on how they entered their name, but usually there is a common string.

Comment: True, depending on the distance metric and how similar the names are. But likewise, there could be different Hadleys in clinic B - or at least that was my line of thought :)